# Extend AsyncHTTPClient to add default success callback

Tags: java, android, inheritance, asynchttpclient

I know this must be simple, but I'm confused. I'm using [AsyncHttpClient](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-Android-Async-Http-Client) in my project. I want to create a new class, say  `AsyncHttpClient2` which will extend `AsyncHttpClient`. This class is currently adding a token to every request. **I want that if the response is `UNAUTHORIZED`, it should perform some action.**

This is the `POST` syntax:

```
String url = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images";
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
params.put("q", "android");
params.put("rsz", "8");
client.post(url, params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {            
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
       // handler code
   }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String res, Throwable t) {
       // error code
    }
});
```

**This is my code:**

```
public class TokenAsyncHttpClient extends AsyncHttpClient {
    public TokenAsyncHttpClient() {
        super();
        this.addHeader("x-access-token", "00000000000000000000000");
    }


    // THIS GIVES ERROR Method does not override method from its superclass

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {

        // PERFORM SOME ACTION HERE

    }
}
```

But this gives me the following error on the `@Override` line:

> Method does not override method from its superclass

What am I doing wrong ? and how can I add a default action in onSuccess ?

Comment: did you try to add super.onSuccess() in onSuccess method?

Comment: @AbdulWaheed it gives me `Cannot resolve mothod onSuccess()`

Comment: pass int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response paramters in super method as well and then let me know

Comment: @AbdulWaheed I tried `super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, response)`. now i'm getting the error: `cannot resolve the method onSuccess(int, ...header, ...JSONObject)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a class (say `TokenHttpResponseHandler`) that extends `JsonHttpResponseHandler` instead of `AsyncHttpClient` and pass it to the client in this way `AsyncHttpClient client.post(url, params, new TokenHttpResponseHandler() {...`.

Then in the `TokenHttpResponseHandler` you can override `OnSuccess` or `OnFailure` and set its default behaviour.

E.g.

```
public class TokenHttpResponseHandler extends JsonHttpResponseHandler {
    public TokenHttpResponseHandler() {
        super();
    }


    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {

        // PERFORM SOME ACTION HERE

    }
}
```

Comment: I made this class: https://gist.github.com/mridah/7985d5beb0056849858d9a657eebbb75 and I'm using it like `client.get(dataUrl, new TokenHttpResponseHandler() {...}` but still the Logs are not displaying

Comment: got it to work by adding `super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, e, errorResponse);` whereever I was using it !!

Answer (score 1):

Reading the [documentation line 1094](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/loopj/android/http/AsyncHttpClient.java#L1094) turned out that AsyncHttpClient doesn't have a method called `onSuccess`. And by reading your question you are using the `get` method from that class which rely on `ResponseHandlerInterface` which have its `onSuccess` method so if you want to change the behaviour of this method you need to implement the `ResponseHandlerInterface` in some class and use that class in your call.